# usage with appostive non restrictive/restrictive

Tags: british-english, restrictive-clauses

When an appositive noun or noun phrase contains an essential element without which a sentence’s meaning would ***materially alter***, do not frame it with commas.

He visited the student bar where he met a student, Jenny, and they discussed college. (specifically Jenny)

He visited the student bar where he met a student Jenny and they discussed college. (might have met other students)

So unless the sentence explicitly requires commas in these sorts of examples they can be viewed as just a pause in the flow of sentence?

Examples are different but certainly not materially altered, just interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed alternative doesn't just mean something different, it doesn't make sense.

> He visited the student bar where he met a student Jenny and they discussed college.

When you put two nouns together without a comma it would be read as a compound noun. So, what exactly is a "student Jenny"? A 'student doctor' is someone studying to be a doctor - so is it someone studying to be a Jenny?

Appositives are a *series* of nouns that identify or add clarity to the identity of that person or thing. The added information is parenthetical - it *adds* to the meaning, but doesn't change it. It could just as easily be placed in parenthesis (brackets, like this) as commas.

Your original sentence:

> He visited the student bar where he met a student, Jenny, and they discussed college.

... could just as easily be written as:

> He visited the student bar where he met Jenny, a student, and they discussed college.

In these two examples above, the information is the same - the difference is that in the first, the emphasis is on the person met being a student and their name, Jenny, is parenthetical. In the second, the emphasis is placed first on the named individual and the added information that they are a student is parenthetical.